# :hover в css

Tags: css

Вот код http://jsfiddle.net/pSzDN/
Нужно чтоб при наведении на  li на элементе появился крестик, но при наведении на любой li всегда появляется крестик с первого li а не с нужного.
Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в позиционировании "хрестиков" — все они расположены в правом верхнем углу, потому что абсолютное позиционирование считается относительно всего блока, а не отдельных пунктов списка. Чтобы исправить, стоит просто дописать в стили:

```
.book li{position:relative}
```